# Left mouse and touchpad click unresponsive

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I am using `14.04` on my `Lenovo ThinkPad T520`. After an attempt to open a page in Firefox resulted in unresponsiveness, I rebooted but just to realize I couldn't control my desktop. Then it became clear only the left mouse button was not responding while the right one was. So I was able to get limited navigation using just the right mouse click, which is very frustrating. I'm typing this on my smart phone.

I had limited success navigating the Settings to Mouse and Touchpad and then selecting Left as the primary mouse click. That would restore the left mouse click for only a little while after which it stopped again.

Seems like another process is hijacking the mouse input after it was restored.

1. Why is this happening? Is it a bug or a virus?
2. How do I fix the problem?

I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu) but it didn't work.

**UPDATE 1:** After another reboot, I lost control of both mouse buttons. I can't do ANYTHING right now. How can I even open a Terminal ?

**UPDATE 2:** I went ahead and tried to power the laptop off, which gave me a popup menu to select what to do with open files (suspend, shut down, etc.).  I chose Suspend and the screen went black.  When it turned back on, the left mouse click worked again.

**UPDATE 3:** The "trick" from above lasts only a minute or so before the left click functionality is lost again.

**UPDATE 4:** I went into `System->Mouse and Touchpad` and set the touchpad to off and then the mouse left click started working again. But the touchpad still is broken after I set it back on.

RELATED:

[Left click not working, right click sporadic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577585/left-click-not-working-right-click-sporadic)

[Ubuntu 14.04 mouse and window focus issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451080/ubuntu-14-04-mouse-and-window-focus-issues)

[Mouse click not working in Ubuntu, Xfce and Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409827/mouse-click-not-working-in-ubuntu-xfce-and-xubuntu)

Comment: 99.99% sure it's not a virus.

Comment: I can't do anything anymore. Even the right click is broken

Comment: Only the mouse navigation works but no button clicks

Comment: Tried a different mouse?

Comment: Both touchpad and the mouse are acting the same

Comment: now the right click is working again but still not the left.  i am typing this on the laptop